Increase root space in RHEL
I have a VM (RHEL, in vSphere), that is running out of space in /dev/mapper/rhel-root. Wich one should be the easiest approach against this problem? I added 10GB to the virtual HardDisk of the VM and it seems it ended up in sda (The previous size was 400GB).
This is the df -h output:
devtmpfs                3,8G      0  3,8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   3,8G      0  3,8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   3,8G   9,3M  3,8G   1% /run
tmpfs                   3,8G      0  3,8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/rhel-root    70G    65G  5,8G  92% /
/dev/sda1              1014M   408M  607M  41% /boot
/dev/mapper/rhel-home   321G   2,8G  319G   1% /home
tmpfs                   777M   1,2M  776M   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                   777M      0  777M   0% /run/user/0

And here is the lsblk one:
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda             8:0    0   410G  0 disk
├─sda1          8:1    0     1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2          8:2    0   409G  0 part
  ├─rhel-root 253:0    0    70G  0 lvm  /
  ├─rhel-swap 253:1    0   7,9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─rhel-home 253:2    0 321,1G  0 lvm  /home
sr0            11:0    1  1024M  0 rom


as your LVM is under the /dev/sda2 which has already been increased, I would do a pvresize /dev/mapper/rhel and change Logical volume size by lvresize -l +100% /dev/mapper/rhel-root (it will grow VG then LV) then use for example growpart / (for xfs) to add space to the partition used for /

instead of the separate growpart command, simply use -r with lvresize!

Does this answer your question? Extend hard drive on Ubuntu (Server)

Accommodate the Physical Volume to the new size (410 GB):
pvresize /dev/sda2 

then extend the Logical Volume to take up all remaining free space, also resizing the filesystem after the process:
lvresize -l+100%FREE -r /dev/mapper/rhel-root

